# How can I force the repository chooser in git gui

Tags: git, git-gui

I put my home directory under version control. If I now start git-gui from my Gnome panel I can only work on this repository. The dialog that lets me browse for or enter a repository location or pick one that I used before is no longer there.

I could not find an according commandline or .gitconfig switch.

How can I force git-gui to display the dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file with the following contents and mark it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /
git gui
```

Save that file somewhere in your `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/bin/my-git-gui`). Then change your gnome-panel launcher to point to that file instead of `git gui`.

(`git gui` issues the prompt you want only if the working directory is not in a git repo. gnome-panel launchers set the working directory to `~`, which in your case is a git repo; the script above is just a wrapper that sets the working directory to something that's hopefully not a git repo.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get the chooser dialog, but you can open a shell, navigate to the other dir you want, and type git gui there. Then it should pop up git gui for that repository instead of the one at your home dir.

Comment: That works, but not if I start git-gui from the panel. There, it always picks my home directory repo.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you try to initialise new repository inside existing repository.

If you put your home directory under version control it means all sub folders are belong to the repository of that home folder.

Schematically it looks like this:

```
-- Home
    |-- Desktop
    |   |-- Project
    |       |-- .git (new repository for Project inside repository for Home)
    |-- Documents
    ... 
    |-- Pictures
    |-- .git (the repository for whole home directory)
```

Therefore we should consider the program works normal in this situation because, as it seems to me, such nested scheme of version control is not valid.